# capistrano error with passenger & git "sh: 2: master: not found"

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano, passenger

I'm setting up capistrano for one of my projects. (it's [Rails 3 Apps with Git, Capistrano and Passenger](http://www.aaginskiy.com/technology/2011/02/deploying-rails-3-apps-with-capistrano/)
It's almost identical situation, except my app dir was under git control, so i had to

> git remote rm origin

before

> git remote add origin ssh://h41319@h33.hvosting.ua/~/www/elmor.org.ua

if i run cap deploy i get an error and the deploy is rolled back... the error as follows

> ** transaction: start
>      * 2013-02-13 18:43:36 executing
>   `deploy:update_code'
>       executing locally: "git ls-remote ssh://h41319@h33.hvosting.ua/~/www/elmor.org.ua\n    master" sh: 2:
>   master: not found
>   *** [deploy:update_code] rolling back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in setting up application dir on the server, now it's ok:

> set :applicationdir, "~/www/#{domain}"